# Fatal error: Call to a member function difference() on string in error on tpl file

Tags: 7, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the value between two fields in my custom node.tpl file. I am trying to convert the code show on http://drupal.org/node/1364744, and I wrote the following one.

```
$birthday = format_date(strtotime($content['field_date_de_naissance']['#items'][0]['value']), 'custom', 'd/m/Y');
$today = date('m/d/Y');
$age = $birthday->difference($today,'years');
print $age;
```

I get this error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function difference() on string in

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified my code by converting the $birthday to dateObject, so it works now.

```
$birthday = new DateObject($content['field_date_de_naissance']['#items'][0]['value']);
$today = date_now();
$age = $birthday->difference($today,'years');
print $age;
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is calling a method (`difference()`) on a string, while just PHP objects and classes implements methods. [`format_date()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/7) is documented to return a string, not a `DateObject`.

> #### Return value
>
> A translated date string in the requested format.

The code I would use depends from what modules you have installed, and which PHP version you are using.

- If you have the [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module installed, and you enabled the Date API module, I would use the following one.

  ```
  $birthday = new DateObject($content['field_date_de_naissance']['#items'][0]['value']);
  $age = $birthday->difference(date_now(), 'years');
  ```
- If you don't have the Date module installed, but you have a recent version of PHP 5 (which means higher than 5.2.0), then I would use code similar to the following one.

  ```
  $birthday = new DateTime($content['field_date_de_naissance']['#items'][0]['value']);
  $age = $birthday->diff(new DateTime())->format('y');
  ```
- If you are still using a PHP version lower than 5.2.0, or you just want code you can use without to worry about the PHP version, I would use the following code.

  ```
  $birthday = strtotime($content['field_date_de_naissance']['#items'][0]['value']);
  $age = format_interval(time() - $birthday, 1);
  ```

  I am not using `format_date()` since it returns a translated string, which is not necessary to `strtotime()` (and probably, it would confuse it).
  `format_interval()` consider a month made of 30 days; for this reason, the code shown above is probably giving a different value than the other methods.

#### Reference

- [`DateTime::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/it/datetime.construct.php)
- [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/it/datetime.diff.php)
- [`DateInterval::format()`](http://php.net/manual/it/dateinterval.format.php)
- [`format_date()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/7)
- [`format_interval()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_interval/7)

Comment: The funny thing that your code give me 20 years for $birthday=01/12/1994, where I get 21 years when I use my code (see it in the answer). can you explain me plz?

Comment: In the comments of format_interval function documentation https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_interval/7 I read that it's consider 30 days as 1 month.

Comment: Yes, it consider a fixed length for a month (2592000 seconds).

Comment: so I should use the difference() method to get the exact value.

Comment: How is it that this didn't become the accepted answer, is it possible to dispute what OP choses as an answer?

Comment: @DanielWaters It's not possible to dispute what the OP chooses as accepted answer, but in the case of an accepted answer written by the user who asked the question, up-voting the question you think is better can make it appear before the accepted one. In any case, the score of an answer is a clear signal the users prefer an answer instead of the others; it should mean something to the future readers.